# How can I automatically check a radio button input based on value in local storage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, state

I have a reusable radio button component. When a value is selected, it is checked and persisted in local storage. However, when I reload the page, although the value has persisted, the check has disappeared from the input element so the user won't know that the value has been saved.

How can I persist the input check on page load?

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useRef } from "react";


function RadioButton({id, value, name, children}) {
  const [radioState, setRadioState] = useState(localStorage.getItem(name) ?? '');
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(radioState));
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.checked = radioState === value;
    }
  }, [radioState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(name);
    setRadioState(storedValue ?? value)
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    setRadioState(newValue)
  }
 

console.log(inputRef)

  return (<>
    <SelectionContainer>
        <Input 
        ref={inputRef}
        type='radio'  id={id} 
        value={value}  name={name} 
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}/>
        <Label htmlFor={id}>
            {children}
        </Label>
    </SelectionContainer>
  </>)
}
```

Comment: I think the problem might be using `localStorage.getItem` inside `useState`. What about trying something like `const initalRadioState = localStorage.getItem(name)` then passing that in?